# Elements in JList does not show up

Tags: java, netbeans

I have created a Netbeans GUI with a jLabel and a jList. I am trying to show the mail subjects from my Gmail into the jList, but nothing comes up. Here's the code that I have:

```
public class FilterExistingUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public FilterExistingUI() {
    initComponents();
}

static FilterExistingUI gmail = new FilterExistingUI();

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
//program-generated private void initComponents() code

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:        
    gmail.read();
}                                        

public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new FilterExistingUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    gmail.read();
}

public void read() {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    try {
        //props.load(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\smtp.properties")));
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "gmail_id@gmail.com","password");

        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("inbox");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        int messageCount = inbox.getMessageCount();

        System.out.println("Total Messages:- " + messageCount);
        jLabel4.setText(Integer.toString(messageCount));

        Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();
        System.out.println("------------------------------");

        DefaultListModel listmodel = (DefaultListModel)inboxList.getModel();
        listmodel.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < messageCount; i++) {
            System.out.println("Mail Subject:- " + messages[i].getSubject());
            listmodel.addElement("Subject:- " + messages[i].getSubject());                
        }    

        inboxList.setModel(listmodel);

        inbox.close(true);
        store.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

The `System.out.println` prints out the list in the output window, but when I run the program, the mail subjects list doesn't show up in the inboxList (my jList), and the message count doesn't show up in jLabel4. I have also added `inboxList.setModel(new DefaultListModel());` in the custom mode in the model property. I am new to Java, and also to Netbeans, so I am confused as to what am I doing wrong here. Is it in the `DefaultListModel()` part? Or in the jList part? Or somewhere else?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't show where you create the JList or add it to the GUI so we don't have all the necessary information. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. We don't have access to your email data, so in the SSCCE you would replace the code in the 'read(...)" method with hardcoded data so that we can actually execute your code to see the results. `I am new to Java,` that is why creating a SSCCE is so important. You learn how to simplify the problem. Usually you will find the problem when you create the SSCCE.

Comment: I built my GUI using the Netbeans palette, so the codes are actually auto-generated and cannot be edited. Also, I'm sorry because I don't understand what you mean by "hardcoded data". Is it like, replace `listmodel.addElement("Subject:- " + messages[i].getSubject());` with manual items like `listmodel.addElement("Subject:- Mail Subject #1");`? And that's all the code I have in my program, except for the autogenerated codes which cannot be edited so I did not include, so I suppose it can be considered as complete?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean by hardcode. Your question is about displaying data in a JList, so where the data comes from is irrelevant. First get the code working by adding hardcoded data to the list. Then once that works you add back in your dynamic code to get the data from a mail server. `I suppose it can be considered as complete?` No it is NOT complete as I stated in my first response. How can we compile and test your code???